# How to draw Thales circle with marked angles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes, circles

I want to draw this picture: [image: Thales circle]

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (S) at (0,0); %does nothing
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (-2,0)  -- (2,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I'm sorry, I'm new to tikz, so sorry for my basic question. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
\psset{linejoin=1}
\pnodes(-2,0){A}(2,0){B}(2;120){C}(0,0){S} \uput[dr](S){$S$}
\psset{LabelSep=0.4, MarkAngleRadius=0.6, linecolor=LightSeaGreen}
\everypsbox{\small\color{LightSeaGreen}}
\pstMarkAngle{S}{A}{C}{$\color{LightSeaGreen}\alpha$}
\pstMarkAngle{A}{C}{S}{$\color{LightSeaGreen}\alpha$}
\psset{linecolor=DeepSkyBlue, MarkAngleRadius=0.9, LabelSep=0.7}
\everypsbox{\small\color{DeepSkyBlue}}
\pstMarkAngle{S}{C}{B}{$\beta$}
\pstMarkAngle{C}{B}{S}{$\beta$}
\psset{linecolor=black}
\pstCircleAB{A}{B}
\psline(A)(C)(B)(A)\psline(C)(S)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can draw this with only `TikZ` (see Zarko's answer) or if you have a lot of work like this (euclidean geometry) with tkz-euclide.
And you can mix `tkz-euclide` with `TikZ`.

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{ \r=6 ;}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(0:\r){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(150:\r){C}
  \tkzDefPoint(180:\r){A}
  \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
  \tkzDrawSegment(O,C)
   \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,O)
   \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
  \tkzLabelAngles[pos=.5](B,A,C A,C,O){$\alpha$}
  \tkzLabelAngles[pos=1.6](C,B,O O,C,B){$\beta$}
  \tkzMarkAngles[mark=|](B,A,C A,C,O)
  \tkzMarkAngles[mark=||,size=2](C,B,O O,C,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the next code you have a 3-4-5 right triangle (egyptian or Pythagoras)

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=36.9,scale=2]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(4,0){C}
  \tkzDefTriangle[egyptian](A,C) \tkzGetPoint{B}
  \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
  \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{O}
  \tkzDrawSemiCircle(O,B)
  \tkzDrawSegment(O,C)
  \tkzLabelPoints(O,A,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
  \tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=teal!20,opacity=.4](B,C,A)
  \tkzLabelAngles[pos=.75](B,A,C A,C,O){$\alpha$}
  \tkzLabelAngles[pos=.75](C,B,O O,C,B){$\beta$}
   \tkzMarkAngles[mark=|](B,A,C A,C,O)
   \tkzMarkAngles[mark=||](C,B,O O,C,B)
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a specific angle for A (here 30 degree)

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-6,xmax=6,ymin=-1,ymax=6]
  \tkzGrid
  \tikzmath{\r = 6 ;}
  \tkzDefPoint(-\r,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(\r,0){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](30:2){c}
   \tkzInterLC(A,c)(O,A) \tkzGetSecondPoint{C}
   \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
  \tkzDrawSegment(O,C)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,O)
  \tkzDrawSemiCircle(O,B)
  \tkzLabelAngles[pos=1](B,A,C A,C,O){$\alpha$}
  \tkzLabelAngles[pos=1.6](C,B,O O,C,B){$\beta$}
  \tkzMarkAngles[mark=|,size=1.5](B,A,C A,C,O)
  \tkzMarkAngles[mark=||,size=2](C,B,O O,C,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,O)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In your third example, could you just define $O$ to be the point $(0, 0)$, $A$ to be the point $(-6, 0)$, $B$ to be the point $(6, 0)$, and $C$ to be the point $(30: 6)$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes it's possible but you need to use the macro `  \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](30:2){c}` to draw the correct angle in A.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I updated the third example !

Comment: I realize now that I should have defined $C$ to be $(60: 6)$ so that $m\angle A = 30^\circ$, $m\angle ACO = 30^\circ$, and $m\angle AOC = 120^\circ$.  That said, the advantage of your approach is that tikz euclide will calculate the coordinates of point $C$ when the angle measures are not "nice".  Thank you for writing tikz euclide.

Answer (score 6):

With pure `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta, 
                intersections, 
                positioning, 
                quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
             > = {Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
myangle/.style = {angle radius=11mm, 
                  angle eccentricity=0.8,
                  draw=#1!70!black, <->,
                  text=#1!70!black},
                        ]
% triangle's coordinates
\coordinate                 (a);
\coordinate[right=6 of a]   (b);
\coordinate[right=6 of b]   (d);
% triangle's coordinate determined by intersection
\path[name path=ac] (a) -- ++ ( 60:6.5);
\path[name path=bc] (b) -- ++ (120:8);
\path[name intersections={of = ac and bc, by=c}];
% triangle's edges
\draw[semithick]    (a) -- (c) -- (b) -- cycle 
                    (b) -- (d) -- (c);
\draw   (b) + (0,+1mm) -- +(0,-2mm) node[below] {S};
% circle
\draw   (b) circle[radius=6];
% angles at A, B, C
\pic [myangle=teal, "$\alpha$"] {angle = b--a--c};
\pic [myangle=teal, "$\alpha$"] {angle = a--c--b};
% angles at C, D
\pic [myangle=cyan, "$\beta$"] {angle = c--d--b};
\pic [myangle=cyan, "$\beta$"] {angle = b--c--d};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** As is known from geometry, angle `\alpha` can be any angle between zero and ninety degrees.

[image]